# cleveref + listings

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, cleveref

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Ref: \ref{test}.
Cref: \cref{test}.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test},label={test}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This produces `Ref: 1. Cref: ?? 1.`. I expected something like `Ref: 1. Cref: Listing 1`.

I get a `LaTeX Warning: \Cref reference format for label type 'lstlisting' undefined on input line 9.`

Comment: Works for me. What versions are you using?

Comment: `("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cleveref\cleveref.sty"
Package: cleveref 2011/03/22 v0.17.9 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `listings' support loaded on input line 2312.)`  Please check you log file.

Comment: I am using the last version from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref

Comment: @YiannisLazarides - I added the same log meesage to my question.

Comment: Can you pleae read you `.log` file and post the version number?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I run your program (I have MacTeX2011), with `Package: cleveref 2012/02/15{} v0.18.4{}` showing in the `log` file`, I don't experience any problems either.

Comment: Hmmm.... Seems like a classic problem when multiple runs (with the .aux files left intact), are required to resolve references. Are you processing this twice?  First run produces your output, the subsequent run produces the desired output.  There should also have been a `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.` in your log file indicating that multiple runs are required.

Comment: The version number is not shown. It just shows `(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty`)... just writing this I realized, that I did not run `latex cleveref.ins`. Now I did it and it's working now. Thanks for your pointers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Add the following to your header:

```
\crefname{lstlisting}{listing}{listings}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{Listing}{Listings}
```

**Solution 2**

Download the newest version from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) (cleveref.dtx and cleveref.ins) and run `latex cleveref.ins`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, your original MWE works fine if you just run it twice.

Comment: It didn't, even after running it 10 times, because of the `LaTeX Warning: \Cref reference format for label type 'lstlisting' undefined on input line 9.`. Seriously, my cleveref version was to old :).

Comment: The link shows version 0.19 2013-12-28. `tlmgr info cleveref` tells I run 0.19 2014-02-26 which I assume is even newer. Still, I ran latex several times, and it would not detect the listing as a listing. Had to go with solution 1 :(

Comment: Regarding solutions 1, it didn't work for me. The problem and the solution is explaind here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/cleveref-doesnt-print-correct-caption-for-listings
Basically, lstlisting should be replaced with listing due to some alias problems.

Comment: @Dennis Just a small hint: The call to `\Crefname` is superfluous in the above case. As mentioned in section 8.1.2 of the [`cleveref` documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), "If the corresponding `\Crefname` is undefined when `\crefname` is called, it will automatically define `\Crefname` to be a capitalised version of `\crefname`, using `\MakeUppercase`."

Comment: For those who run into the same issue having installed the current version as @mcnesium: Make sure that `listings` is included BEFORE `cleveref`!

Comment: If you came here based on question search terms, but use `\lstinputlisting`, then your solution is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338141/cleveref-with-hyperref-uses-wrong-label-when-referring-to-line-in-code-listing