# cleveref doesn't print correct caption for listings

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, cleveref

I want to set the caption for referenced listings:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\crefname{lstlisting}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}

Ref: \ref{test}.
Cref: \vref{test}.
\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test},label={test}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

According to [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/cleveref-listings), I'd expect `Quelltext 1` but it prints `listing 1`.

What is wrong?

Comment: `\crefname{listing}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}` works. I don't know why the package decided to use `listing` instead of `lstlisting`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
\crefname{listing}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}
\Crefname{listing}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}
```

There is an alias from `lstlisting` to `listing`, but apparently it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\crefname{listing}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}
\Crefname{listing}{Quelltext}{Quelltext}

Ref: \ref{test}.
Cref: \vref{test}.
\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test},label={test}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: It is important to load package cleveref _after_ loading package listings.

Comment: @Florian `cleveref` should always be the *last* loaded package (with perhaps just a few exceptions).