# Is it possible to get the name of the referenced item together with a label?

Tags: cross-referencing

If I define a figure, table, code listing or anything similar with a caption and a label, how can I get the item name together with the reference label?

For example, if I define a figure:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{figures/figure.png}
    \caption{Some figure.}
    \label{figure:some-figure}
\end{figure}
```

what do I need to do to avoid writing: `Figure \ref{figure:some-figure} shows` and write `\ref{figure:some-figure} shows` to produce the following output:

"Figure 1 shows" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `cleveref` which provides the command `\cref{}` which automatically adds "figure" or "table" depending on the nature of the float you are referring to. You also have the capitalized version `\Cref{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a figure.}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is a table.}\label{tab}
\end{table}

See \cref{fig} or \cref{tab}. \Cref{fig} shows that\dots. \Cref{tab}, on the contrary,\dots

\end{document}
```

Edit: if you are using listings with a custom name, you should give it explicitly to `cleveref`:

```
\crefname{lstlisting}{code listing}{code listings}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{Code Listing}{Code Listings}
```

See also: [cleveref + listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/cleveref-listings). By the way, I think you need to load `cleveref` before `listings`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, however the cleveref package seems to ignore the alternative name for the listings package: \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Listing}, it just writes "listing 1", instead of "Code Listing 1". I just found the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/cleveref-listings