# appendices reference with varioref

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, varioref

I am using the appendices and the varioref package to refer at them.

The code for the appendices is the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
    \appendixpage
    \noappendicestocpagenum
    \addappheadtotoc

    \chapter[MATLAB codes]{List of MATLAB codes} \label{app:MATLAB}

    \begin{lstlisting} [language=Matlab, caption=Reconstruction function., label=code:reconstruction]

    some text

    \end{lstlsiting}
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
```

when i quote them in the text i do it this way:

```
In appendix \vref{app:MATLAB} we have the code \vref{code:reconstruction}
```

the results are strange, like:"In the appendix chapter A we have the code ?? A.1 on page 121".

Is it normal?

I am using (in this order) these packages:

```
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem: it was caused by the clevref package which has a problem with listings.

The solution is explained here: [cleveref + listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/cleveref-listings)

Thanks a lot to Dennis!